# How to check if Redshift user can alter table

Tags: amazon-redshift

In Redshift, I am checking Users' grants. How do I know if they can alter tables?

I can know if they can drop tables because "Only the owner of the table, the schema owner, or a superuser can drop a table." - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DROP_TABLE.html No such qualification exists for alter table: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html

HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE provides info about other privileges, but not alter table: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a response from AWS Support. tl;dr: alter table can be run by those, and only those, who can drop table.

"""

This is because, determining whether or not a user can alter a table, works in a similar way to that were one determines whether or not a given user can drop a table. That is, only the owner of the table, the schema owner, or a superuser can Alter a table. According to our documentation, "The right to modify or destroy an object is always the privilege of the owner only." [1].

[1] Default database user privileges - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Privileges.html

Therefore, to see the users with alter table permissions for a specific table, there is need to determine the owner of that specific table by running the following command:

Kindly note that in this example, the 'sales' table is used. You can edit this as you see fit. To see all the table owners, the AND section of the WHERE clause can be removed.

```
====Query to see table owners====
SELECT n.nspname AS schema_name
, pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) AS table_owner
, c.relname AS table_name
, CASE WHEN c.relkind = 'v' THEN 'view' ELSE 'table' END
AS table_type
, d.description AS table_description
FROM pg_class As c
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
LEFT JOIN pg_tablespace t ON t.oid = c.reltablespace
LEFT JOIN pg_description As d
    ON (d.objoid = c.oid AND d.objsubid = 0)
WHERE c.relkind IN('r', 'v')
AND c.relname = 'sales'
ORDER BY n.nspname, c.relname;
```

You can also see all the superusers who have permissions to Alter table by running the following query:

```
====Query to see superusers====
SELECT usename FROM pg_user WHERE usesuper = 'true';
```

The combination of both results will enable you to see all the users which have alter table permissions.

"""